# Half wave plate in front of polarising beam splitter?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, randomness

I have seen (in e.g. quantum random number generators) a half wave plate in front of a polarising beam splitter. But why do we need it and what would be different if we did not have it?

Comment: could you please improve with a link to a schema ? thank you

Answer (score 2):

For varying the beam intensity. By changing the orientation of the $\lambda/2$ plate, you are changing the polarization of the light reaching the polarizer. Intensity of the light passing the polarizer is $I=I_0\cos^2(2\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle of the $\lambda/2$ plate relative to some axis.

In principle, one could tune the intensity using just the polarizing mirror (beam splitter). However, the orientation or the mirror is often determined by the rest of the setup and thus fixed. The $\lambda/2$ plate adds the necessary degree of freedom.